# The secret value can't be converted to key name and value pairs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, secretsmanager

I already have a secret created by cloudformation template with the following key/value format:

```
  UserPassword:
Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
Properties:
  Name: mysecret
  GenerateSecretString:
    SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "test-user"}'
    GenerateStringKey: "password"
    PasswordLength: 16
    ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
```

And i've created a rotation lambda, but when i rotate the secret i get only plain text format without key/value pair as the following error:
**The secret value can't be converted to key name and value pairs.**

here's my lambda code:

```
import boto3
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    arn = event['SecretId'] 
    token = event['ClientRequestToken']
    step = event['Step']

    # Setup the client
    service_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    

    metadata = service_client.describe_secret(SecretId=arn)
    print(metadata)
    
    
    if not metadata['RotationEnabled']:
        logger.error("Secret %s is not enabled for rotation" % arn)
        raise ValueError("Secret %s is not enabled for rotation" % arn)
        
        
    versions = metadata['VersionIdsToStages']
    
    if token not in versions:
        logger.error("Secret version %s has no stage for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))
        raise ValueError("Secret version %s has no stage for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))
        
        
    if "AWSCURRENT" in versions[token]:
        logger.info("Secret version %s already set as AWSCURRENT for secret %s." % (token, arn))
        return
    elif "AWSPENDING" not in versions[token]:
        logger.error("Secret version %s not set as AWSPENDING for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))
        raise ValueError("Secret version %s not set as AWSPENDING for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn))


    if step == "createSecret":
        create_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    elif step == "setSecret":
        set_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    elif step == "testSecret":
        test_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    elif step == "finishSecret":
        finish_secret(service_client, arn, token)

    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid step parameter")


def create_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    
    # Make sure the current secret exists
    service_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=arn, VersionStage="AWSCURRENT")

    # Now try to get the secret version, if that fails, put a new secret
    try:
        service_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=arn, VersionId=token, VersionStage="AWSPENDING")
        
        logger.info("createSecret: Successfully retrieved secret for %s." % arn)
    except service_client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
        # Get exclude characters from environment variable
        exclude_characters = os.environ['EXCLUDE_CHARACTERS'] if 'EXCLUDE_CHARACTERS' in os.environ else '/@"\'\\'
        # Generate a random password
        passwd = service_client.get_random_password(ExcludeCharacters=exclude_characters)

        # Put the secret
        service_client.put_secret_value(SecretId=arn, ClientRequestToken=token, SecretString=passwd['RandomPassword'], VersionStages=['AWSPENDING'])
        logger.info("createSecret: Successfully put secret for ARN %s and version %s." % (arn, token))


def set_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    pass

def test_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    pass


def finish_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    # First describe the secret to get the current version
    metadata = service_client.describe_secret(SecretId=arn)
    current_version = None
    for version in metadata["VersionIdsToStages"]:
        print(version)
        if "AWSCURRENT" in metadata["VersionIdsToStages"][version]:
            if version == token:
                # The correct version is already marked as current, return
                logger.info("finishSecret: Version %s already marked as AWSCURRENT for %s" % (version, arn))
                return
            current_version = version
            break

    #Finalize by staging the secret version current
    service_client.update_secret_version_stage(SecretId=arn, VersionStage="AWSCURRENT", MoveToVersionId=token, RemoveFromVersionId=current_version)
    logger.info("finishSecret: Successfully set AWSCURRENT stage to version %s for secret %s." % (token, arn))
```

Comment: Which line generates the error? Can you provide a Minimal code example that exhibits the problem, rather than this full program?

Comment: if i knew i would not ask

Comment: Can you please provide the JSON value for 'step' that you are passing to the lambda function which generates this error?

Comment: it's a rotation lambda so the value of step is different based on which iteration of the rotation you are in: createSecret, testSecret, setSecret, or finishSecret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update the default rotation template so that it generates the new secret in the same format which you have specified in your cloudformation template. By default, the rotation lambda just creates a new secret string and populates only that value. If you add the following lines to the rotation lambda function, your newly rotated secret will be in a JSON format that allows the Web UI to parse it into name/value pairs.

You will need to add **import json** at the top of your script, and then modify the create_secret function as shown below:

```
def create_secret(service_client, arn, token):

    # Make sure the current secret exists
    service_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=arn, VersionStage="AWSCURRENT")

    # Now try to get the secret version, if that fails, put a new secret
    try:
        service_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=arn, VersionId=token, VersionStage="AWSPENDING")

        logger.info("createSecret: Successfully retrieved secret for %s." % arn)
    except service_client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
        # Get exclude characters from environment variable
        exclude_characters = os.environ['EXCLUDE_CHARACTERS'] if 'EXCLUDE_CHARACTERS' in os.environ else '/@"\'\\'
        # Generate a random password
        passwd = service_client.get_random_password(ExcludeCharacters=exclude_characters)
        # Create a username/password JSON object to pass to secrets manager
        generated_passwd = passwd['RandomPassword']
        secret_template = {"password": generated_passwd,"username": "test-user"}
        # Put the secret
        service_client.put_secret_value(SecretId=arn, ClientRequestToken=token, SecretString=json.dumps(secret_template), VersionStages=['AWSPENDING'])
        logger.info("createSecret: Successfully put secret for ARN %s and version %s." % (arn, token))
```